# iOS 7 pluralization + Arabic language

Tags: ios7, string-formatting, arabic, pluralize

The basic problem is that the following line:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"باقي للشراء %d", 3];
```

returns a string with a form of "3 *arabic_text*".

When I write a line:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d باقي للشراء "];
```

again returns a string with form of "3 *arabic text*".

When I write a create a string like this:

```
NSString *digitThree = @"3";
NSString *expressionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"باقي للشراء %@", digitThree];
```

`expressionString`'s value becomes a string with a form of "3 *arabic text*".

But when I write a code like this:

```
NSString *someChar = @"d";
NSString *expressionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"باقي للشراء %@", someChar];
```

`expressionString`'s value becomes a string with a form of "*arabic text* d".

This behaviour probably has something to do with the fact that digits are accepted in arabic alphabet, but Latin alphabet characters are not.

I am using iOS7 localized pluralization feature (Localized Property List File section [here][1]).

Localizable.stringsdict file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>%d days</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
        <string>%1$#@num_days@</string>
        <key>num_days</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
            <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>

            <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
            <string>d</string>

            <key>one</key>
            <string>يوم %d</string>

            <key>other</key>
            <string>أيام %d</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>




</dict>
</plist>
```

From the code I use this like:

```
[NSString localizedStringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%d days", @"'%d' denotes the number of days. The expression would, for example, evaluate to: '4 days'"), 1])
```

But I can never get this call to return "*arabic text* 1", it always returns "1 *arabic text*".

**EDIT:**

Thank you, Holax.

At first, your answer didn't seem like something useful. But now I see it is.
I was confused by a couple of things.

1) Using NSLog() and printing NSString values during debugging. It seems that printing NSString values with Arabic content this way prints them in the **opposite** direction than the way they are displayed when put as a UILabel content.

2) The way the UILabel wraps content into multiple lines when the text involves arabic characters combined with digits. Specifically, in my case I had:

"1234567890128 redemption code", which was wrapped into:

"123456789012

*arabic text* 8"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in general, in the `Localizable.string` file you can play the actual translation like:

e.g. *in English*:

```
"%d day" = "Expiration: %d days";
```

then *in other Language*:

```
"%d day" = "<expiration in days>: %d"
```

the key is the same, but the value can hold the formatter at different location.

---

furthermore the Arabic language's direction is `RTL`, opposite to the English language on the screen which is `LTR`, therefore you may need to consider about that fact and count with it in your language file, like:

```
<key>other</key>
<string>%d أيام</string>
```